# Why does "sucker" mean "unexpected" in "Sucker Punch"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, meaning-in-context, slang

*[Sucker punch](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0978764/)* seems to mean "an unexpected punch" in slang. What is the origin of this term and why does *sucker* mean *unexpected* in *sucker punch*?

Comment: I don't have a definitive etymology of the term, and even the Oxford English Dictionary doesn't offer any help with this one. However, *sucker* is often used to mean a naive or stupid person, one who is easily taken advantage of. In boxing, a person who doesn't protect himself at all times could certainly be described as a sucker.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The *sucker* here has a much longer history than some would have you believe. Basically, *sucker punch* derives from one of the meanings of the word sucker (NOAD):

> **sucker** 2 *informal* a gullible or easily deceived person.

Therefore, a "sucker" would be easy to fool with a surprise punch. Etymonline dates the use of [the term](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=sucker&searchmode=none) to 1836, and it appears to derive from the expression for a young mammal before it is weaned, i.e. one that is still sucking at its mother's teat.

Note that despite what Thursagen states, Etymonline also gives different dates for the term *suckerpunch*:

> **suckerpunch** (n.)
>   also sucker punch, 1926, from sucker + punch. Figurative use by 1929. As a verb by 1942. Related: *Sucker-punched*.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. The implication in boxing would be you've been *suckered* by an unexpected or rather underhand blow. Wikipedia says the term is generally reserved for situations where the way in which the blow has been delivered is considered [unfair or unethical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sucker_punch)

Comment: The sucker in the expression means that if we fight face to face, you have a chance to see a punch coming, but I treat you like a sucker or fool if I surprise you on the side or back, when you cannot see. So the sucker punch is any sneak attack, a form of cheating by treating you like dirt, not a peer deserving of respect and rules.

Answer (score 5):

Its [origin](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sucker+punch) is in boxing,:

> An unexpected blow, as in They felt that suddenly raising the interest rate was a sucker punch to the administration . This expression comes from boxing, where it is used for a punch delivered unexpectedly; boxing great Jack Dempsey wrote, "The right lead [for a right-handed boxer] is called a sucker punch." [Slang; mid-1900s]

[Here](http://www.ringsidebygus.com/boxing-terms.html) states the exact date:

> An unexpected punch that catches a person completely off guard. The term sucker punch dates back to 1947 in the sport of boxing.

Why? Being coined by Jack Dempsey who just called it a sucker punch for his reasons, I think it'd be hard to find out. Try asking Jack.

Comment: There's no evidence that Dempsey coined it; he just offered an early definition of the term. Indeed, your ringsidebygus.com quotation states that the term dates to 1947, but the Dempsey quotation comes from his book *Championship Fighting*, which was published in 1950.

Comment: Dempsey may not have coined the term, but he *popularized* it. That's why it is associated with him.

Comment: @Tom Au - IMHO the person responsible for popularizing something generally deserves the accolades traditionally given them. I do not agree with the modern mania for trying to find the absolute first use, no matter how obscure.